# How to access object3D of ambient light for datGUI

Tags: aframe

I want to use datGUI to control the intensity of the lights in my scene. But first, I must get the light as an object, with its parameter, 'intensity'. From the AFrame docs (and my last SO question answered), the way to access the underlying THREE.lights is to use entity.getObject3D(type). This works when accessing meshes, but I'm not able to get a response to lightEl.getObject3D('light'). returns undefined

I have a simple scene with just a sphere and an ambient light. In a custom component, I reference the ambient light element, and then use the getObject3D() method with many different type arguments, and cannot get a reference to the THREE.light.
I can see (in the console) the (ambient light's) THREE.group, which contains the THREE.light, with type: "AmbientLight". But using this as the type argument does not work either.

```
 <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent("dat-gui", {
            init: function(){               
                let sceneMap = scene.object3DMap;
                console.log('scene map: ', sceneMap);

                let amLtEl = document.querySelector("#ambientLight");
                console.log('ambient Light Entity: ', amLtEl);

                let amLtEl3D = amLtEl.object3D;
                console.log("amLtEl3D ", amLtEl3D.children);

                let amLtGet3D = amLtEl.getObject3D('AmbientLight');
                console.log("El.getObject3D('AmbientLight')", amLtGet3D);

                let amLtGet3Dl = amLtEl.getObject3D();
                console.log("El.getObject3D('light')", amLtGet3Dl);
            }
        });

<a-scene background="color:#444">
            <a-entity id="torusKnot" geometry="primitive: torusKnot" position="0 0 -4" material="color: #999"></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="camera" camera orbit-controls="target: 0 0 -4" dat-gui></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="ambientLight" light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.5"></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="directionalLight" light="type: directional; target: #torusKnot" position="0 5 0"></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
```

I expected el.getObject3D('light') to return a reference to the underlying THREE.light, as this works perfectly with ('mesh'), but nothing I use returns the THREE.light.
I have a glitch of the project here
https://glitch.com/~ambient-light-gui

and here is the same thing on my server, so you can see the console.
http://www.sensorium.love/experiments/yamashiro/bonsai/ambientLightGUI.html

Comment: great! now my GUI is adjusting the lights. Now I want to adjust the params of a torus knot (p and q). But accessing those params is not obvious.  


let torusKnotg3D = document.querySelector("#torusKnot").getObject3D('mesh'); 

tnParams = gui.addFolder("Torus Knot");
 tnParams.add(torusKnot, "p", 0, 12).name('p'); 

Error: Object "[object HTMLElement]" has no property "p"
below is my glitch. edit if you like
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/290f3b68-dc2c-4b7a-a3cf-7f7c1bfc4df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the scene to load. When your component `init` runs the rest of the entities might not be ready:

```
sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
   var light = document.querySelector('#ambientLight").getObject3D('light');
}
```

Comment: That worked! The next step is driving parameters on a torus knot, specifically the p and q of the THREE.TorusKnotGeometry object. how to reference it?

let torusKnotg3D = document.querySelector("#torusKnot").getObject3D('mesh'); 
tk3Dp=torusKnotg3D.geometry.metadata.parameters;
tnParams = gui.addFolder("Torus Knot");
tnParams.add(tk3Dp, "p", 0, 12).name('p');

doesn't throw an error, but does not change the torus, so the THREE.paramaters must not be in that path. But I can't find the right path. Any suggestions?

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/290f3b68-dc2c-4b7a-a3cf-7f7c1bfc4df1

Comment: Better to open a separate question